# This process cannot access the file because the file is being used by another process (java.nio.file.FileSystemException) in KOTLIN

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compile-time

In Kotlin when I tried to run file I faced with this issue.
It says 'This process cannot access the file because the file is being used by another process' here in English.

**This is the command line error in compile time**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**To solve it follow these steps**

*1 ) In your IDE probably DefaultPreview shows as chosen, click on it and change it to app*

[image]

*2) It should look like this at the and:*

[image]

This should solve your problem.